# minikube start error: could not find capabilities for domaintype=kvm

Tags: kvm-virtualization

What are installed for minikube:

```
$ ls -al /usr/local/bin/
-rwxr-xr-x  1 me me 26406912 Jun 15 09:11 docker-machine
-rwxr-xr-x  1 me me 12096944 Jun 14 17:06 docker-machine-driver-kvm
-rwxrwxr-x  1 me me 50359943 Jun 14 15:35 kubectl
-rwxr-xr-x  1 me me 87434272 Jun 14 15:35 minikube
```

Trying to start cluster by minikube

```
$ minikube start --vm-driver=kvm
Starting local Kubernetes v1.6.4 cluster...
Starting VM...
E0614 12:07:39.515994   14655 start.go:127] Error starting host: Error creating host: Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: virError(Code=8, Domain=44, Message='invalid argument: could not find capabilities for domaintype=kvm ').

 Retrying.
E0614 12:07:39.517076   14655 start.go:133] Error starting host:  Error creating host: Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: virError(Code=8, Domain=44, Message='invalid argument: could not find capabilities for domaintype=kvm ')

sudo /usr/sbin/kvm-ok 
INFO: /dev/kvm does not exist
HINT:   sudo modprobe kvm_intel
INFO: Your CPU supports KVM extensions
INFO: KVM (vmx) is disabled by your BIOS
HINT: Enter your BIOS setup and enable Virtualization Technology (VT),
      and then hard poweroff/poweron your system
KVM acceleration can NOT be used

$ dmesg | grep kvm
[    2.114855] kvm: disabled by bios
[    2.327746] kvm: disabled by bios
[  120.423249] kvm: disabled by bios
[  222.250977] kvm: disabled by bios
```

I am new to kubernetes. Any idea how to fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As the output of `dmesg` suggested, the solution is to enable visualization in BIOS.

1, Power on PC and open the BIOS.

2, Go to `security` section and enable visualization.

(This may differ for different machines.)